# JTable doesn't show up on button click

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get my GUI to display a table on button click, but it doesn't show up as I expected it to.

I thought adding adding the table into the panel retrospectively would work, but it doesn't. Any guidance will be much appreciated, thanks.

````
public class gui {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    private JTable transition_table;

    gui() {
        this.panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        
        Integer[] variables_options = new Integer[10];
        Integer[] alphabets_options = new Integer[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < variables_options.length; i++) {
            variables_options[i] = i + 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < alphabets_options.length; i++) {
            alphabets_options[i] = i + 1;
        }

        JComboBox<Integer> variables_combo_box = new JComboBox<>(variables_options);
        JComboBox<Integer> alphabets_combo_box = new JComboBox<>(alphabets_options);
        JButton generate_button = new JButton("Generate Table");

        JPanel controls = new JPanel();
        controls.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3));
        controls.add(new Label("Variables: "));
        controls.add(new Label("Alphabets: "));
        controls.add(new Label(" "));
        controls.add(variables_combo_box);
        controls.add(alphabets_combo_box);
        controls.add(generate_button);

        JTextArea transition_table_panel = new JTextArea();

        this.panel.add(controls);
        this.panel.add(transition_table_panel);

        generate_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String[] target_alphabet_count = new String[(Integer)alphabets_combo_box.getSelectedItem()];
                String[][] target_variable_count = new String[(Integer)variables_combo_box.getSelectedItem()][(Integer)alphabets_combo_box.getSelectedItem()];

                for (int i = 0; i < (Integer)alphabets_combo_box.getSelectedItem(); i++) {
                    target_alphabet_count[i] = String.valueOf(i);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < (Integer)variables_combo_box.getSelectedItem(); i++) {
                    target_variable_count[i][i] = String.valueOf(i);
                    
                    for (int j = 1; j < (Integer)alphabets_combo_box.getSelectedItem(); j++) {
                        target_variable_count[i][j] = "";
                    }
                }

                transition_table = new JTable(target_variable_count, target_alphabet_count);
                transition_table_panel.add(transition_table);
            }
        });
    }
}```
````

Comment: I don't see where you define a `JFrame` for your `JPanel` display.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: 1) a JTable should be added to a JScrollPane so you can see the table headers. 2) After adding components to a visible frame you need to invoke revalidate() and repaint() on the panel to invoke the layout manager.